# jQuery datepicker not showing calender on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code in the header:

```
$(function($)
{
    $.datepicker.regional.nl = {
        closeText: 'Sluiten',
        prevText: '&#116;',
        nextText: '&#117;',
        currentText: 'Vandaag',
        monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],
        monthNamesShort: ['jan', 'feb', 'mrt', 'apr', 'mei', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec'],
        dayNames: ['zondag', 'maandag', 'dinsdag', 'woensdag', 'donderdag', 'vrijdag', 'zaterdag'],
        dayNamesShort: ['zon', 'maa', 'din', 'woe', 'don', 'vri', 'zat'],
        dayNamesMin: ['zo', 'ma', 'di', 'wo', 'do', 'vr', 'za'],
        weekHeader: 'Wk',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional.nl);
});

$(function()
{
    $( '#FormContainer' ).on( 'click focus', '.datepicker, .future-datepicker', function()
    {
        var el = $( this );
        if( el.attr( 'class' ) === 'datepicker' ){
            el.datepicker({ 
                maxDate: new Date,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        }else if( el.attr( 'class' ) === 'future-datepicker' ){
            el.datepicker({ 
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When the .datepicker-element receives the focus through a click on it, it does not show the calender, but a list like the image below. When it receives the focus through the TAB-key, it shows a proper calender.
What can I do to get the same result when I click on it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI? Check if you're referencing the jQueryUI css

Comment: I am using jquery-ui-1.11.4. If I didn't the calender would not have shown on TAB!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out te be quite simple. When I click on the input-field the browser shows a number of autocomplete-options. The calendar is shown underneath the autocomplete options. The solution was to add autocomplete="off" to the html of the input-field.